# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'assign_add'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to apply the attributes of an image to another image using Keras/Tensorflow and python but when I run my code I get the error shown above. The error comes specifically from:

```
x[..., 0].assign_add(103.939)
x[..., 1].assign_add(116.779)
x[..., 2].assign_add(123.68)
```

The rest of my code seems to work fine as it compiles, processes the images, etc, but at the end of the run, I get this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Somehow your `keras` code has created `x` as a `numpy` array.  What is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

`.assign_add` is a tensorflow function, not a numpy function.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add?hl=gl

Can you try this?

`tf.assign_add(x[..., 0],103.939)`

Comment: I haven't imported tensorflow to my project so is there any way to do this through Keras? Because of this I get this error now: NameError: global name 'tf' is not defined

Comment: I am confused, ```add_assign``` is apparently a tensorflow function.